# Abelianisation Group theory

Tags: group-theory

Could you please help me with this statement? 
If H is a normal subgroup of G and G/H is abelian, then there exists a surjective group homomorphism from G^(ab) to G/H.
Is G^(ab) the notation for the group: G/ [G,G]. Any element in this group is a coset of the commutator subgroup of G, in G?

Comment: You have the correct interpretation of the notation.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!

Comment: But have you any idea what the next step could be? Thanks! The elements in the commutator subgroup are not necesseraly commutators, but are for sure products of cummutators. And if H is normal in G, then gH = Hg for any element g in G. If G/H is abelian then it means that if you have g1H and g2H (2 left cosets of H in G) in this group G/H. Than g1Hg2H is equal to g2Hg1H...

Comment: If $G/H$ is abelian, what can you say about the relation of $H$ and $[G,G]$?

Comment: [G,G] is normal in G. and by definition: the quotient group G/ [G,G] abelian. It also holds that if H is a normal subgroup of G for which G/H is abelian (which we have! ) then [G,G] is contained in H. [G,G] is by definition a group so in this case [G,G] is a subgroup of H. So the order of [G,G] must be a divisor of the order of H.

Answer (score 1):

A hint: if $K$ and $H$ are subgroups of $G$ such that $K\subset H$, there is a natural surjective homomorphism from $G/K$ to $G/H$. If this is not a familiar fact, try proving it.